# Update TFS Build Status via Powershell

Tags: powershell, tfsbuild

I've a TFS Build Definition setup where, I execute a powershell script for security hardening, applying final patches etc.

Sometimes this powershell script can fail and I would like to change the status of build to be un-successfull or fail. Is there a way to change this TFS Build status via a powershell?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$script:TFServerName  = $ServerName
$script:TFServer      = [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TeamFoundationServerFactory]::GetServer($ServerName)
$script:TFBuildServer = $TFServer.GetService([Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.IBuildServer])
$spec = $TFBuildServer.CreateBuildDetailSpec($TeamProject, $DefinitionName)
$spec.Status = 'Failed'
```

Make sure you've `Add-Type` the right versions of the TFS assemblies.  I'm assuming here that since the properties support setters, they communicate back to the server to affect the change.  But I'm not 100% sure of that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I pieced together from MSDN:

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client")
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client")


$tfsServerAddress = "http://{tfs hostname}:{port}/{CollectionName}"
$build = "{build definition name}_{build date}.{build count for the day}"

#update build status
$tfsProject = [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory]::GetTeamProjectCollection($tfsServerAddress)
$tfsBuildServer = $tfsProject.GetService([Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.IBuildServer])
$spec = $tfsBuildServer.CreateBuildDetailSpec($teamProject)
$spec.BuildNumber = $build
$builds = $tfsBuildServer.QueryBuilds($spec).Builds

if ($builds[0].TestStatus -eq 'Succeeded'){
    echo "updating test status:" $builds[0].TestStatus "to $testOutcome"
    $builds[0].TestStatus = $testOutcome
}

if ($builds[0].Status -eq 'Succeeded'){
    echo "updating build status:" $builds[0].Status "to $testOutcome"
    $builds[0].Status = $testOutcome
}
$tfsBuildServer.SaveBuilds($builds)
```

Keep in mind that you need a special permission to update build status